# phpBB as a Oauth service provider

Tags: php, oauth, phpbb, service-provider

I'm building a website and would like to allow users from a specific phpBB forum to log in using their existing forum account. The websites are uncorrelated and I plan on giving access to other phpBB forums at a later time, so I can't share databases or something like that.

Does phpBB have a oauth service provider functionality by default ? I've found many ways to log in to a phpBB using third party providers such as G+ or Facebook, but not the other way around.

Comment: are you asking if users can use facebook for example to login to the phpbb forum or if members can use phpbb to login to facebook?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

phpBB authentication is fully self contained so this won't be possible.

Comment: Sure this is possible - just make or find a plugin which implements an OAuth2 API